# Session security: Zend_Session_Validator_HttpUserAgent

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, session

There is a nice [article on denzone about avoiding identity theft](http://devzone.zend.com/article/11906). However it was written before `Zend_Session_Validator_HttpUserAgent` came in.

How do I use `Zend_Session_Validator_HttpUserAgent`?

```
Zend_Sesion::registerValidator(new Zend_Session_Validator_HttpUserAgent());
Zend_Session::rememberMe();
```

Is that all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this function is apart of a [family](http://docs.gnulife.cn/ZF/ZendFramework-1.0.4/documentation/api/core/Zend_Session/Zend_Session_Validator_Abstract.html) of classes that do this:

```
This method should be used to retrieve the environment variables that will be needed to 'validate' a session.
```

This is so stupid it hurts.  When your session is hijacked using XSS it will probably be sent as a GET request.  In the incoming HTTP request will contain the  USER_AGENT, as well as many other "environment variables" that the attacker can control.

Calling this approach a waste of time is an understatement.  This is **not** a security feature, and sessions are can **never** be protected in this way.

If you want to protection your sessions [scan for xss](http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner.htm), patch CSRF,  use https for the *entire session*.  Read the OWASP top 10 for 2010,  especially A3: "Broken authentication and session management."

Comment: This is not 100% safety for sure. However, the attacker can send anything he wants, but he does not know what I'm comparing it to (e.g. session data & ip saved previously to the database), right? When I suspect the difference, I regenerate session ID.

Comment: The $_SESSION['REMOTE_ADDR'] is the only thing the attacker cannot influence,  and there for is the only comparison that will add any secuirty to the system.  However,  this breaks some corporate load balancing which will send traffic out on an arbitrary ip.  There is no point in checking any other value,  the attacker is going to try and just do a "javascript:document.cookie='whatever'",  and when that doesn't work he'll change his headers using tamper data or whatever until it works.  Checking the user agent gives you 0% secuirty.

Comment: @takeshin User Agent Switcher: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59  or go to about:config in your address bar.

Comment: @The Rook Thanks for all the responses. I agree that this technique is not to be trusted in general. But I disagree, that it is 0% security. The key here is "*until* it works". Checking IP is quite good, but checking IP & User agent is better. (Some networks use shared IP). However, HTTP is stateless, and nothing gives 100% security for session.

Comment: @takeshin  I disagree,  this system does not prevent the session from being stolen,  no matter the condition.  Thus it is 0%.   An attacker could just forge the entire header by default because of completely broken security systems like the one you are describing.

Comment: @The Rook Anyway, I still haven't seen the example usage for the validator I was asking for :)

Comment: @takeshin Yeah, I haven't heard you speak of a security system that stops attacks.

Comment: if($_SESSION['USER_AGENT']!=$_SERVER['spoofed_USER_AGENT']){
die('hacker');
}